# Virtual console pauses video and audio playback running in KDE

Tags: ubuntu, kde, audio, console, video

In Kubuntu 14.04, when I switch to one of the virtual consoles by pressing `CTRL-ALT-F1...F6` all audio and video playback running in the GUI gets interrupted and continues only when going back to X.

I have no idea what causes this and if this is the intended behavior or a bug. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. If anyone is interested, here's a solution: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/213149